# Building error: "ansible-galaxy: not found" while trying to build Ansible Execution Environment

Tags: image, ansible, containers, builder, podman

**How do I fix this issue?**

I ran: $ ansible-builder build --tag ansible-execution-environment -v 3

STEP 6/7: RUN ansible-galaxy role install -r requirements.yml --roles-path "/usr/share/ansible/roles"
/bin/sh: 1: ansible-galaxy: not found

Error: error building at STEP "RUN ansible-galaxy role install -r requirements.yml --roles-path "/usr/share/ansible/roles"": error while running runtime: exit status 127

**Here are my steps:**

```
execution-environment.yml

version: 1

build_arg_defaults:
   EE_BASE_IMAGE: '\< quay.io_insert_here \>'

dependencies:
   galaxy: requirements.yml
   python: requirements.txt
   system: bindep.txt

additional_build_steps:
   prepend: |
      RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools


**requirements.yml**

---

collections:
   - name: awx.awx
   - name: ansible.utils
   - name: cisco.ios
   - name: community.general
   - name: netbox.netbox
   - name: yoctoalex.xc_cloud_modules


**requirements.txt**

ansible-core==2.12.7
pyats
genie
python-libnmap
XlsxWriter
pynetbox
configparser


**bindep.txt**


nmap
python-libnmap
python3-openpyxl
```

Comment: Is your `EE_BASE_IMAGE: '\< quay.io_insert_here \>'` a child of an `ansible-runner` image? In other words, does it contain `ansible(-galaxy)`?